# Automatically Generating API Reference for Custom Endpoints in MedusaJS v1.3.17

Tags: next.js, openapi, openapi-generator, medusajs, medusa

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm currently working with MedusaJS version 1.3.17 for our e-commerce backend. As our project has grown, we've added several custom endpoints to cater to our specific needs. To ensure our team and potential third-party developers understand the functionalities, I'm looking to create a comprehensive API reference.

Manually documenting each endpoint is becoming cumbersome, especially when we make frequent updates. I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically generate an API reference for these custom endpoints in MedusaJS.

Has anyone faced a similar challenge or can recommend tools/methods that integrate well with MedusaJS? Any pointers or best practices would be immensely helpful.

Thank you in advance!